# Compare all items from List and return in new list

Tags: c#, linq, list, compare

I have an array of Objects

```
List<Card> cardsOnTheScreen = new List<Card>(5);
```

Every Card has enum Honurs field, there are 14 kinds of honurs (Jack, Queen etc.) Does anyone can help me to find which of these elements are more than once on the screen? The output should be e.g List of cards which are two or more the same kind of honour.

Comment: You need `GroupBy` & `Count`. Better give it a try rather than asking complete answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by `Honurs`, filter by the count, then get the cards form the group:

```
var result = cardsOnTheScreen
    .GroupBy(c => c.Honurs)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Here's an example. Assuming we have a setup like this:

```
public enum Honours { Ace, One, Jack, Queen, King }
public enum Suit { Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades }

public class Card
{
    public Honours Honours { get; set; }
    public Suit Suit { get; set; }
}
```

Then we have a list filled with cards:

```
List<Card> cardsOnTheScreen = new List<Card>
{
    new Card { Honurs = Honurs.Ace, Suit = Suit.Clubs },
    new Card { Honurs = Honurs.Ace, Suit = Suit.Hearts },
    new Card { Honurs = Honurs.Ace, Suit = Suit.Spades },
    new Card { Honurs = Honurs.One, Suit = Suit.Clubs },
};
```

Using the above code, would give the output of:

```
Ace, Clubs
Ace, Hearts
Ace, Spades
```

Comment: Thanks it works ! If there will be Two Pairs e.g Ace,Ace & King,King will result.Count == 4? and have in it those 4 items?

Comment: Yes it will have 4 items, try it out!

Answer (score 0):

solution you should use LINQ to find or compare item in collection without using loop

```
List<Card> cardsOnTheScreen = new List<Card>(5);
List<Card> newList = cardsOnTheScreen.Where(obj => (Object with some condition));
```

after this you will get new list that you want